# Inserting user sexual orientation on register form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a register form and I am allowing users to select their `gender` and the gender the user is interested in.

What I need help with is connecting the dots. For example if user selects their gender as `female` and then for gender interested in `female` is selected, then it should enter the user as `gay` for the `sexuality` attribute.

If the user selects their gender as `female` and they select both `male` and `female` for interested in then the user should be saved to the database as `bisexual` for their sexuality.

register form:

```
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Interested in" %><br />
        <div class="check-gender">
          <div class="check check-male" style="margin: 0">
            <input id="user_sexuality_male" name="user[sexuality]" type="checkbox" value="Male" class="jqTransformHidden">
            <label for="user_sexuality_male">Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="check check-female" style="margin: 0">
            <input id="user_sexuality_female" name="user[sexuality]" type="checkbox" value="Female" class="jqTransformHidden">
            <label for="user_sexuality_female">Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with programming, but you should perhaps use the term "sexual orientation" instead.

Comment: I can change, but that's database information so it would never be shown as `sexuality` to the user :).

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes

Comment: what do you want to actually happen in the code? Where is this code going to be located? eg do you want this as something that happens behind the scenes, and the orientation never gets shown to the user (and thus could be a before-create hook in your rails model?) or are you setting this in the form as something visible to the user (in which case it has to be javascript)

Comment: ie: you need to give us more info on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I prefer for it to take place in the views. To do a before-create in the model I would need to create a new attribute on User, which feels like too much for determining the user orientation. The selection of genders is visible to the user. I included a screenshot.

Comment: I wouldn't even write this code. I'm guessing you're storing both the user's gender and interest, so if the only purpose it serves is to display something based on the combination of these attributes you can create a view helper that boils whichever of the six possibilities into the term you want to display.

Comment: @Eric I am not storing their interest. I am only storing `gender` and `sexuality`. But perhaps the easier route is to create a new `interest` attribute and then do a helper. I was trying to avoid creating a new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That logic would have to be written in the controller. A simple if statement, if gender == interest then orientation = gay else orientation = straight. Access the params in the controller to get that. If you want to show the answer in real time (withouth refreshing the page) then you need to do this in javascript.